# How does this Ruby command line work? Seemingly running a CMD script with Ruby

Tags: ruby, cmd

I'm examining how [`ridk enable`](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/wiki/The-ridk-tool) works in order to figure out how to hook it into Travis CI build logic. <sub>(The Ruby installation I'm studying is a [RubyInstaller+Devkit](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) installed locally; the commands are run from the "Start Command Prompt with Ruby" prompt.)</sub>

I've got stuck at a Ruby command line executed under the hood whose working is a mystery to me:

```
"C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\ruby" --disable-gems -x 'C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\ridk.cmd' enable
```

It seems to run a CMD script (?!) with Ruby -- which isn't supposed to be possible. Running it with `-rtracer` in place of `--disable-gems` shows that the execution somehow ends up jumping into `C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/ruby_installer/runtime/ridk.rb`.

**Could someone explain to me how this command line works?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man ruby`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ruby):

> -x[directory]
>   Tells Ruby that the script is embedded in a message. Leading garbage will be discarded until the first line that starts with `#!`
>   and contains the string, `ruby`
>   Any meaningful switches on that line
>   will be applied. The end of the script must be specified with either
>   EOF ^D ( control-D ^Z ( control-Z or the reserved word `__END__` If the
>   directory name is specified, Ruby will switch to that directory before
>   executing script.

Which means the `ridk.cmd` has embedded ruby code.

The `directory` is optional, as indicated by both the square brackets around the name and the description. If provided, it *should* be directly after `-x` without any space, which effectively allows it to be an optional argument.

Comment: But it says "directory", and `C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\ridk.cmd` is not a directory...

Comment: Oh, I see, the "directory" is only recognized if it's specified directly after `-x` without space. This is contrary to the standard practice, it usually doesn't matter if there's a space or not.

Comment: (See? Even you missed that tiny-but-critical detail when copypasting the help text!)

Comment: Ruby starts evaluating [ridk.cmd at line 37](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/blob/1435e9db8e97743dfd924280b2118ce8cdb9b064/resources/files/ridk.cmd#L37) – the first line starting with `#!` and containing the word `ruby`

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I did not judge this necessary for the answer, but I'm gonna add it anyway, it's true that the description is not entirely explicit